# Is there an API resource for the Reminders object existing in Google Calendars' GUI?

Tags: google-calendar-api

in google calendar you can create 3 different objects:

- Event
- Reminder
- Task

I try to figure out which fields are provided by the google calendar for reminders.
I found the documentation for calendar events: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events
And I also found the documentation for calendar tasks (and task lists): https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks

So I know which fields are provided and what there meaning is.

But unfortunately I am unable to find the documentation for the reminders and which fields they offer.
Does anyone know where/how to find the documentation for the reminders? Or which fields they provide in total? Or are they just events from a special kind?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### IMPORTANT:

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no API resource for the new GUI reminder object. So ATM it can only be used through the GUI.

**There is an issue created in the Public Issue Tracker for creating an API for reminders. Please use [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283) and add your two cents. Thank you !**

---

You are on the correct documentation site for the reminders. You see, reminders are a property of the [`Event resource`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations).
If you take a deeper look at the Event resource structure (scrolling down) you will find the property `"reminders"`:

```js
 "reminders": {
    "useDefault": boolean,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "method": string,
        "minutes": integer
      }
    ]
  },
```

Further down you have the Value, Description and Notes for each property ordered by Property Name.

Here is a screenshot of the reminders property details:

[image]

Here you have a bit more explanation about the [concept of reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders) in Google Calendar.

And this [help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) also has some useful.

But I believe the most important concept is that of the [**Default reminder**](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#default_reminders) which is reminder setting that applies to all events created in that Calendar.

#### Note:

The **Calendar Event's reminder property** is set to use the **Default Reminder** settings of the calendar to which it belongs by *default*. And can be overridden by specific settings for the event in question.

Comment: Thx for your response. I did see that section and as far as I understood it, this part is for reminders for a specific event. But in the GUI as shown in my screenshot in the question I am also able to create a reminder with a **title**, a **dateTime**, a **recurrence** and an option for an *allDay** reminder. I could not figure out if that is an own entity itself (like an event or task) or if it is just another "view" for an event. Do you know that?

Comment: @thehandofNOD You are right there are two types of remiders. I have elaborated a bit more about it in my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thx again, but the problem is: In the GUI I can give the reminder a title. According to the API documentation this is not possible for default reminders: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList

But I also don't find an attribute in the `event` description which marks an event as a reminder. Somehow google has to know that this kind of object shall be shifted until it is marked as done.
So unfortunately I am not sure if it is really a default reminder and I am also not sure if it is just an event.

Comment: Ah ok thx a lot. Could you provide the information and the links in the answer? Then I can mark it as solution. Thx a lot

Comment: @thehandofNOD I have edited the question, changed the order of importance of the answer, and put the links. Thank you!